# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI warning for Font-awesome font files

Tags: spring-mvc, font-awesome

I recently started using font-awesome v4.5.0. It was working like a charm until I upgraded to java 8 from java 7 and spring framework to v4.0 from v3.2

Now, font-awesome icons appear as squares. Browser console (firebug) shows-

> NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/myapp/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.5.0

and tomcat's catalina.out logs show following warnings-

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2 in DispatcherServlet with name 'myappservlet'`

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myappservlet'`

`No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myappservlet'`

Location of 'fonts' folder is correctly specified in font-awesome.min.css's @font-face src. (There are no changes apart from java version and spring framework version. It suddenly stopped working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue.
do you have something like this in your web.xml?

```html
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
   </servlet-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment those lines solved the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks @martin. removing the url-pattern ' / ' solved the issue.:-)